# How to make a Cocoa binding to a property of optional type in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, option-type, cocoa-bindings

I am exploring the use of Swift for a Mac Cocoa application - using Xcode 8.2.1, and it seems I hit a roadblock regarding Cocoa bindings.

In this toy Core Data document-based project, I added an `NSArrayController` in the StoryBoard. I need to bind it to a `NSManagedObjectContext` so that my user interface works by itself. I followed the solution outlined in Technical Q&A QA1871 (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1871/_index.html).

So I want to add a property of type ManagedObjectContext to my ViewController class.

I naturally declared it as an optional:

```
var moc: ManagedObjectContext?
```

But when I enter the property name in the bindings inspector of InterfaceBuilder, it complains: there is a red exclamation mark, and hovering over it pops up this error message:

```
“The Managed Object Context binding expects to be bound to an object of type NSObject, but moc is of type ManagedObjectContext?”
```

And it fails at run time too.

changing the type to `ManagedObjectContext!` doesn’t help: IB complains in exactly the same way.

changing the type to a non optional `ManagedObjectContext` silences the IB error, but now my ViewController class doesn’t compile anymore. The error I get is:

```
class ViewController has no initialiser
```

I completely understand this error message. And I can add an initialiser. But I get this new error message:

```
property ‘self.moc’ not initialised at super.init call.
```

I understand that one too, but what can I do? At initialiser-time, the `managedObjectContext` is not yet known. In Objective-C I would set it to nil, which I cannot do since the property is not an optional any more.

Do I really need to allocate a dummy sentinel ManagedObjectContext, just to make the compiler happy?

This would be ugly as hell, far worse than the nil value we use in Objective-C. Swift in that case, would not be safer, but less safe than Obj-C.

I find this idea repulsive. Or did I miss something?

Or is Swift fundamentally incompatible with this Apple-recommended Cocoa bindings pattern? That would be a pity too.

Note that an equivalent Objective-C implementation works just fine. In Objective-C, the property is declared as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext * _Nullable moc;
```

Edit: a zip archive containing two toy sample projects, one in Objective-C, the other in Swift 3, can be downloaded from http://dl.free.fr/pWkoKQLOc

Edit: here is where I set the viewController's managed object context:

```
class Document: NSPersistentDocument {

override func makeWindowControllers() {

    let myMoc = self.managedObjectContext

    // Returns the Storyboard that contains your Document window.
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "Document Window Controller") as! NSWindowController

    let myViewController = windowController.contentViewController as! CarViewController
    myViewController.moc = myMoc

    self.addWindowController(windowController)
}

}
```

`myViewController` is created by storyboard, and I can only set its `moc` after it has been initialised. This in turns requires that the property be an optional *or* to have a dummy actual value to use as a sentinel value in replacement for `nil`

Comment: In Swift the managed object context is supposed to be non-optional.

Comment: That comment is not helpful, not to mention wrong. If is it not optional, to which value do you set it to, when the value is not yet available?

Comment: What type is `ManagedObjectContext` ?

Comment: In the Core Data template the managed object context is lazily loaded in AppDelegate. To be used with array controller and bindings override the appropriate `init` method in the controller and initialize the context there.

Comment: @vadian. Nope. There is one managed object context per NSPersistentDocument. It therefore cannot be (and is not) lazily loaded in AppDelegate

Comment: You can download an archive with two sample projects from http://dl.free.fr/pWkoKQLOc

Comment: Try `dynamic var moc: NSManagedObjectContext?`.

Comment: @Willeke adding `dynamic` doesn't fix the IB as reported by Interface Builder, *but* the app now works at run time. Do you have a theory about why this works?

Comment: Bindings uses KVO which requires Dynamic Dispatch. See the "Key-Value Observing" section of [Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID57)

Comment: Well that comment helped me at least, @Willeke. I was trying to bind to an optional variable and couldn't work out why bindings didn't update when that variable was set.